# Why is PostgreSQL rejecting my password when I try to migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pg

I have PostgreSQL installed via this [link](http://excid3.com/blog/installing-postgresql-and-pg-gem-on-mac-osx/) and all seems good. I can use the GUI interface and I can see my databases but when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
 $ rake db:migrate
 (in /Users/tamer/Sites/sample)
 rake aborted!
 FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "tamer"
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 database: test
 encoding: unicode
 host: localhost
 user: postgres
 password: mypass
 timeout: 5000
```

Where "mypass" is my password I set.

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zqqj.jpg) of it running

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well something doesn't quite add up. The error message refers to a user "tamer" but the `database.yml` file has the "postgres" user. Are you sure this is the database.yml file that's being used? What happens when you try to log in with the GUI tool with either user?

Comment: i am not sure my user is being called on the database.yml file...when i changed from :user to :usersssfsd to see if anything was happening i got the same error ....but if i comment out the entire block i do get an error....funky stuff